# MPAndroidChart: chart only displaying during animation

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Below is my simple code for a line chart. If I use this code but only have one Entry, one point shows on the graph, which is good. If I add any more, like I have below, nothing at all shows, unless I add "newchart.animateX(3000);, in which case the chart shows for 3000ms and then disappears.... what gives?

```
    LineChart newchart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    ArrayList<Entry> YAxis = new ArrayList<>();
    Entry startingtemp = new Entry(0,3);
    Entry next = new Entry(1,6);
    YAxis.add(next);
    YAxis.add(startingtemp);


    LineDataSet temps = new LineDataSet(YAxis, "fuck");
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
    dataSets.add(temps);

    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
    newchart.setData(data);
    newchart.animateX(3000);
    newchart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Have you tried just removing the call to `invalidate`? It shouldn't be necessary as you're already using `animateX`.

Comment: I have tried that since posting. Still does same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the reason it wasn't working was because I added an x value of 1 before 0. when i switched the order in which i added the two entrys to the array, it started working fine.